# ColdFusion 8 always opens .XLS, want .XLSX

Tags: excel, coldfusion, excel-2007, mime-types

I am using ColdFusion 8. Doing something like this:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=abc.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel">
<html>
```

But I get a file like `abc.xlsx.XLS`.

The reason I'm trying to get an `XLSX` is because sometimes the `XLS` version is so large and Office 2007 gets stuck opening it or takes way to long.

Only workaround right now is to wait, open the `XLS` in Office 2007, save as `.XLSX` and then open it faster.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try changing the content-type to `application/octet-stream`. Maybe if the client doesn't know it's getting an Excel document it won't try to "fix" the extension.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!
I tried it and these are the results:
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyPriceList.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream">  
"Excel cannot open the file 'abc.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not 
been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"
Even if instead of opening attachment I save it, I cannot open it (same message)

Comment: I was just using abc as an alias for MyPriceList, please ignore the discrepancy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that the slow opening is because you are providing the data in an HTML format, not because of the extension.  You could test this by saving the file directly from the browser, renaming it with the xlsx file extension, and opening it.

If you want to save data in an Excel format directly, I would check out Ben Nadel's [POI CFC project](http://www.bennadel.com/projects/poi-utility.htm).

Comment: Thanks to all. Also found some resources on using XML to load excel file directly.

Comment: https://blogs.wharton.upenn.edu/brainstorm/2008/01/reading-and-writing-excel-file.html

and 

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/461-Creating-Microsoft-Excel-Documents-With-ColdFusion-And-XML.htm

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the MIME type for Excel 2007 `.xlsx` files is `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`.  I found an article on the [Office Resource Kit Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/office_resource_kit/archive/2009/06/30/register-office-2007-file-format-mime-types-on-servers.aspx) that calls this out after googling around a little.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!
I tried it and these are the results:
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyPriceList">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">  
This opens the file, but slowly, I have to do a 'save as' as it doesnt have an extension.
Once I do a save as xlsx, and open the saved file, it opens really fast. (so same issue as downloading a .xls file)

Comment: <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyPriceList.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">  

"Excel cannot open the file 'abc.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not 
been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file". Even if instead of opening attachment I save it, I cannot open it (same message)

Comment: I was just using abc as an alias for MyPriceList, please ignore the discrepancy

Comment: I also notice first attempt (below) it opens it as a XSLX, rather than XLSX.

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyPriceList"> <cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">