# How to read an MS Excel 2007 with query in ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, excel-2007

I am using coldfusion8 and mysql5 and UI have to read/select approx 900,000 (9 Lacks) records from an MS Excel 2007 file and insert them into my database. I am using the query below, which I think is for MS Excel 2003:

```
SELECT * FROM "Excel 8.0; DATABASE=abc; HDR=YES".[myfile$]
```

How do I read from an MS Excel 2007 file?

Thanks,
Kishor

Comment: You don't mention the version of ColdFusion that you're using - if it is CF 9, have you tried using `<cfspreadsheet>`? See documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html . If you're still on CF 8, then there could be a lot of work required on your part (I assume the issue is XLSX files): http://rahulnarula.blogspot.com/2009/03/coldfusion-and-excel-2007-integration.html

Comment: This link might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240528/coldfusion-8-always-opens-xls-want-xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Check out the field of [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering). This problem may not be as straightforward as you first assumed.